# ¿Cómo establecer propiedades de un control Rating programaticamente en Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, web

Yo realizo una consulta a mi base de datos con estos resultados, debo crear un medidor de rating de un cliente. ¿Puedo desde el código C# setear la propiedad `CurrenRating` del control con el resultado de la consulta?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="asm" runat="server" >  </asp:ScriptManager>
<h6>Rating</h6>
<ul>
    Food Quality  <asp:Rating ID="FoodQuality" runat="server" CurrentRating="0" MaxRating="5" EmptyStarCssClass="icon_star" FilledStarCssClass="icon_star voted" StarCssClass="icon_star voted" WaitingStarCssClass="icon_star" /><br />
</ul>
```

Comment: Por favor muestra lo que has hecho para implementar esto y qué te dificulta para terminarlo. Ten en mente que no hacemos el trabajo de nadie, y mucho menos gratis.

Comment: Nadie te esta pidiendo q hagas algun trabajo..esto es un foro abierto...y para que tengo que mostrar todo el codigo?? El que sabe de que hablo se dara cuenta q la respuesta no es mas de un par de lineas de codigo y posiblemente hasta 1 sola.

Comment: Efrain, pedimos que se publique mas código para poder ver lo que se ha intentado anteriormente y así poder contribuir con una solución completa. Al [ver esta pregunta por la primera vez](http://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/28127/3), lucia como una pregunta como la que menciona @LuiggiMendoza. Se ve que has agregado el código y se agradece el intento.  Ahora, permite que la comunidad vea lo que preguntas y esperemos que se encuentre una solución pronto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregue controles Rating de Telerick , elimine el de AjaxControlToolkit

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />

      Food Quality<telerik:RadRating RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="ratingFoodQuality" runat="server" ItemCount="5" SelectionMode="Continuous" Precision="Half" Orientation="Horizontal" ReadOnly = "true"></telerik:RadRating>
      Price<telerik:RadRating RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="ratingPrice" runat="server" ItemCount="5" Value="0" SelectionMode="Continuous" Precision="Half" Orientation="Horizontal" ReadOnly = "true"></telerik:RadRating>
      Punctuality<telerik:RadRating RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="ratingPunctuality" runat="server" ItemCount="5" Value="0" SelectionMode="Continuous" Precision="Half" Orientation="Horizontal" ReadOnly = "true" ></telerik:RadRating>
      Courtesy<telerik:RadRating RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="ratingCoutesy" runat="server" ItemCount="5" Value="0" SelectionMode="Continuous" Precision="Half" Orientation="Horizontal" ReadOnly = "true"></telerik:RadRating>
```

Estableci las propiedades  asi

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           ratingFoodQuality.Value = 3; 
           ratingPrice.Value = 4; 
           ratingPunctuality.Value = 2;
           ratingCoutesy.Value = 1;   

        }
```

y me resulto esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]